# 'NUnit.Framework.List' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I'm trying to make the same thing like in [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html?m=1) thread, but I'm getting error:

> Error 3   'NUnit.Framework.List' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'NUnit.Framework.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the part error:

```
List maps = new List();
foreach (XmlSchemaType schemaType in xsd.SchemaTypes.Values)
{
  maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaType.QualifiedName));
}
foreach (XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
{
  maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
}
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: You most likely want to use `System.Collections.List`, not `NUnit.Framework.List`.

Comment: @Rob  Hi, could you please correct me here ? what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I just noticed; it's likely because you're not using a generic `List`, so it's using `NUnit`'s list. Change your declaration to `var maps = new List<XmlSchemaType>();` instead (change `XmlSchemaType` to whatever `ImportSchemaType` returns.

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot for your help, how could i accept your answer? `List<XmlTypeMapping> maps = new List<XmlTypeMapping>();`